# Update D3 text width by adding new width

Tags: d3.js, dynamic

I have a D3 text added inside a rectangle , where the value of text field is  updated programtically. Now I need to expand the width based on the text value length  but making sure to keep the default width as min width. 
I have tried getting the new value.length and updating the d3 text width like below.

```
var length = //length of the updated text value
var elm = d3.selectAll("[id=s1]");
elm.attr('width', function(d) { return  length; });
```

This works fine but when i delete the text D3 text box also shrinks all the way. I need to keep a default width and then just increase if the value is longer than that. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to check for a minimum value:

```
elm.attr('width', function() { 
    return  length < minimumValue ? minimumValue : length;
});
```

Where `minimumValue` is, of course, your minimum value.

Comment: Hi Gerardo, I tried this out but it is always returning the length value regardless the condition... Any idea why?

Comment: It makes no sense. Please paste the exact code you're using.

Comment: var elms = d3.selectAll("[id=s1]");
               var minValue = 130 + 'px';
                var dynamic = length + 'px';
               elm.attr('width', function() { 
    return  dynamic < minValue ? minValue : dynamic;
});

Comment: Indeed, and I hope you know why: adding a string to a number gives a string as the result.